# Best way to design this code?

Tags: c++

I have a log function which takes a parameter, which prints out the name of some HW

```
logEvent("LOG THIS HW select = %s", NAME[selection]);
```

To determine what to print I have:

```
const char* NAME[] =
{
"A"
"B"
}
```

This was in the header but then I got multiple implementations problems, I want this to be accessed by many files.  How can I put this kind of data in a header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put a declaration in the header:

```
extern const char* NAME[];
```

and put the definition in *one* cpp file:

```
const char* NAME[] = {"A", "B"};
```

Answer (score 3):

Adjust `logEvent` so `selection` is passed as a parameter. You can then keep the string table local to that function.